# Upload single image with Laravel and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to do a div with a image and a form to change this image. My idea is doing this with ajax to it can the image change dinamicly. This is my code:

[HTML]

```
<h3>Configurar módulo</h3>                          
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'password/change', 'method' => 'POST', 'id'=>'formImg1_homeModules')) !!}
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}" id="img1Token_homeModules">                           
   <label>Imagen de fondo:</label>      
   <input id="img1Input_homeModules" type="file" name="img1">
   {!!link_to('#', $title = "Guardar", $attributes = array('id' => 'submitImg1_homeModules', 'class' => 'btn btn-default center-block', 'style' => 'width: 50%; margin-top:3%;'), $secure = null)!!}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

[JQuery]

```
$("#submitImg1_homeModules").click(function(){
    if($("#img1Input_homeModules").val() == ""){
      alert("Debe seleccionar una imagen");
    }else{
        var route = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/ajax/config/uploadImage";
        var image = $("#img1Input_homeModules").val();
        var token = $("#img1Token_homeModules").val();
        var module = "img1";

        $.ajax({
          url: route,
          headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          data:{image,module},
          success: function(res){
            alert(res);
          },
          error: function(res){
            console.log(res);
          },
        });
    }
});
```

[PHP/Laravel(Controller)]

```
 /**
 * @Post("ajax/config/uploadImage")
 */
public function UploadImage(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax()){
        if(strcmp ($request->module , 'img1' ) == 0){
            \Storage::disk('local')->put('modules/prueba.jpg', \File::get($request->image));
            return 1;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is this, when I save the image in modules/prueba.jpg, It doesn't save as a jpg file and I don't know why. I am doing something wrong?. There are another easier way to do this?

Comment: Have you checked the `\File::get($request->image)` to see that it there's actually a file there? You may be calling it wrong. I think you should be calling `$request->file('image')` instead.

Comment: Hi Azeame. When I use \File::get($request->image) I get this error: File does not exist at path 'name image', so there are something wrong. I try to calling how you say but I get a null field, I mean, when I do $request->file('fieldImage') I get  null value.

Comment: In your ajax script you've renamed the file field contents to `image` so shouldn't you be calling `$request->file ('image')`? In any case you can validate that you actually have a file in the request field using `$request->file('image')->isValid()`.

Comment: I try validate the file, but I get a error 500, it's strange becouse $request->file('image) return the file name but when I save it, don't do it correctly.